# Setting parameters in Kedro Notebook

Tags: python, kedro

Is it possible to overwrite properties taken from the parameters.yaml file within a Kedro notebook?

I am trying to dynamically change parameter values within a notebook. I would like to be able to give users the ability to run a standard pipeline but with customizable parameters. I don't want to change the YAML file, I just want to change the parameter for the life of the notebook.

I have tried editing the params within the context but this has no affect.

```
context.params.update({"test_param": 2})
```

Am I missing something or is this not an intended use case?

Comment: Concrete use case: I create a pipeline that calculates mean and std of some metric over last 90 days. I would like to have this in production but allow users to run the same pipeline but for any number of days they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kedro supports specifying [extra parameters](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/04_user_guide/03_configuration.html#specifying-extra-parameters) from the command line by running

```sh
kedro run --params "key1:value1,key2:value2"
```

which solves your second use case.

As for the notebook use case, updating `context.params` does not have any effect since the context does not store the parameters on `self` but rather pulls them from the config every time the property is being called.

However you can still add extra parameters to the context object after it being instantiated:

```py
extra_params = context._extra_params or {}
extra_params.update({"test_param": 2})
context._extra_params = extra_params
```

This will update extra parameters that are applied on top of regular parameters coming from the config.

Comment: Exactly what I was after.